# VS code remote x11 не может извлечь переменную DISPLAY при подключении к удаленному серверу

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

Я использую Windows VS Code и расширения «Remote SSH», «Remote X11», «Remote X11 (SSH)» для подключения и получения графики с удаленного сервера.

Я запускаю VcXsrv, Pageant. Передача графики работает, если я подключаюсь к серверу напрямую, например через Pageant. Она работает также во встроенном терминале VS Code, если я **вручную** ставлю "export DISPLAY = localhost: 10.0" на удаленном сервере.

Но не хотелось бы ставить каждый раз DISPLAY руками. Его должен ставить Remote X11, но при попытке ее установить пишется **Failed to get DISPLAY: Error: Invalid cygwin unix socket path**

Comment: так поставьте строку `export DISPLAY=':10'` в ~/.bashrc или какой у вас shell запускается по умолчанию?

Comment: @DiD, да, как вариант. Но в любом случае это костыль, и оказывается он работает только когда одновременно с vs code есть соединения просто через putty. То есть расширения x11 не работают, даже отключал их. Когда нет дополнительного соединения через putty, vs code пишет **Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0**

Comment: Ну, если вы не определили эту переменную, её в рабочем окружении не будет. Обычно её определяет запущенный X-сервер. Но вы то конектитесть через ssh. Кстати, как вам скорость работы по сети?

Comment: Ну вот на сколько я понял ее должно ставить как раз это расширение, "Remote X11". По скорости, какой нибудь матлотлиб нормально работает(что в принципе мне и нужно), а вот eog например очень долго.

Comment: Ну само по себе пробрасывание X11 по ssh - тема довольно устаревшая лет на 20. Трафа жрет немеренно, грузит и сервер и клиент нормально так... Я как бы не знаю, чем вам vnc не угодил. А по клиентам - это да, X11 поддерживает только putty, он там и отрисовывает все это безобразие на экране клиента.